# How to pass html input value to php? - variable not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am having problem to get the value of a text field to php from html.

I want to make a select statement to filter latitude and longitude by date from mysql database but the statement is not work. `$_Post[datee];` is not getting the value from text box.

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php 
    $dbname            ='u769748933_tr'; //Name of the database
    $dbuser            ='u769748933_ta'; //Username for the db
    $dbpass            ='adamas'; //Password for the db
    $dbserver          ='mysql.1freehosting.com'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
    ?>

<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Google Map API V3 with markers</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
 #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
 new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
 new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
 var center = null;
 var map = null;
 var currentPopup;
 var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
 var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
 bounds.extend(pt);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: pt,
 icon: icon,
 map: map
 });
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: info,
 maxWidth: 300
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
 if (currentPopup != null) {
 currentPopup.close();
 currentPopup = null;
 }
 popup.open(map, marker);
 currentPopup = popup;
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
 map.panTo(center);
 currentPopup = null;
 });
 }
 function initMap() {
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 mapTypeControl: false,
 mapTypeControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
 },
 navigationControl: true,
 navigationControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });


 <?
 $date=$_POST['datee'];
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poi_example where datee='".$date."'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 $name=$row['name'];
 $lat=$row['lat'];
 $lon=$row['lon'];
 $desc=$row['desc'];

 echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
 }

 ?>

 center = bounds.getCenter();
 map.fitBounds(bounds);

 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body  style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<button onclick="initMap()">show map</button>
<INPUT TYPE = "Text"  NAME = "datee">
<div id="map"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: You need `<form></form>` tags  with the proper action and method, and a submit button

Answer (score 0):

you miss the `<form method="POST">` tag

Answer (score 0):

Create your FORM like this

```
<form method="POST">
 <!-- input fields here -->
</form>
```

and then get those values in PHP like `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<form>` tag in the following line of code

```
<button onclick="initMap()">show map</button>
<INPUT TYPE = "Text"  NAME = "datee">
```

like this,

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Enter Date">
  <button type="submit" onclick="initMap()">show map</button>
</form>
```

The form tag is used to create a form for user input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `input`s within `form` tags. Also, you need to define the forms `method`(if not given, it will be set to `GET`).

So, your code should look like this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <button onclick="initMap()">show map</button>
  <input type= "Text"  NAME = "datee">
</form>
```